# React native - remove space between drawerIcon and item text on Drawer.Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-drawer

I'm trying to adjust space between icon and text in drawer screen.

Here's an image to explain better.

[image: Image showing space between icon and drawer item text]

Here's my code

```
<Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={(navigation) => ({
        drawerItemStyle: {
           borderRadius: 0,
           width: '100%',
           marginLeft: 0
        }
      })}>
      <Drawer.Screen 
         name="HomeScreen" 
         component={HomeScreen} 
         options={{ 
            headerShown: true,  
            headerTransparent: true, 
            headerTitle: "", 
            title: 'Start Delivery',
            drawerIcon: (({focused}) => <Icon name="car" size={25} color={focused ? "#288df9" : "#777"} style={{padding:0, margin:0}} />)
         }} 
      />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default `Drawer` uses a `DrawerItemList` which is a list of [DrawerItems](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/drawer/src/views/DrawerItem.tsx). Looking at the source code, the view that wraps the label implements a `marginLeft` of `32`. This is hardcoded and cannot be changed without using dirty tricks.

Let us test this using the following example.

```js
function App() {
  return (
     <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{drawerIcon: () => <View style={{height:20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "red"}} />}}  />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The above uses a `View` as a dummy image with a red background. Here is the result.

[image]

Adding a `marginRight` of `-32` to our icon removes the "gap" completely.

```js
function App() {
  return (
     <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{drawerIcon: () => <View style={{height:20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "red", marginRight: -32}} />}}  />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is the result.

[image]

This is not ideal since we have to do this for each icon, thus we could create a custom component and reuse it.

```js
const CustomIconComponent = ({focused, name}) => {
    return <View style={{marginRight: -32}}>
        <Icon name={name} size={25} color={focused ? "#288df9" : "#777"} />
    </View>
}
```

Then, use it for each screen.

```js
options={{ 
        
    ...
            title: 'Start Delivery',
            drawerIcon: (({focused}) => <CustomIconComponent focused={focused} />)
         }}
```

There is a second way. We could create a [custom drawer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/). This would allow us to not use the `DrawerItem` component but a custom component with custom stylings.

Comment: A negative margin is definitely the best approach, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another option that solves that problem as well is to use negative `marginLeft` directly in the Text rendered inside every list Item. You can reach this solution using `drawerLabelStyle` property inside option prop as is showed below:

```js
function App() {
  return (
     <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ drawerLabelSyle: { marginLeft: -10 } }}  />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```